# Database does not exist but it does in pgsql

Tags: laravel-5.8, postgresql-11

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=dms
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=test
```

here is my code but it keeps throwing error   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL:  database "dms" does not exist (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = public and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE') did I miss something?

Comment: What do you get when you run `psql -h localhost -U postgres -l`?

Comment: I am sorry I am in windows thank you for your comment  hope you will give me the answer thank you

Comment: problem solved thank you

Comment: @PurushottamTiwari  can you let me know how you did it, cause currently I am having the same issue